# Special Character is getting added in react-table empty rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have an HTML page which fetches RESTful service data and renders as react-table. When RESTful service response doesn't contain any data, the react-table is displaying special character in the empty rows under span tag as 
 Ã‚

I have included charset=UTF-8 in the head tag of HTML page. But this didn't resolve the issue.

I am using the required libraries from https://cdnjs.com/libraries

React-table code:

```
<script type="text/babel" charset="utf-8">
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable.default
          data={[RESTful response JSON]}
          columns={[
            {
              Header: 'Functional Test Results',
              columns: [
                {
                  Header: 'Process Date',
                  accessor: 'processDate'
                },
                {
                  Header: 'Test Category',
                  accessor: 'testCategory'
                },
                {
                  Header: 'Testcase Name',
                  accessor: 'testCaseName'
                },
                {
                  Header: 'Test Subcase Name',
                  accessor: 'testSubCaseName'
                },
                {
                  Header: 'Status',
                  accessor: 'status'
                },
              ],
            }
          ]}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
          showFilters={true}
          noDataText="Oh Noes! No data available."
          filterable={true}
        />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```

Can someone please suggest me workaround on how to get rid of the special character from the empty react-table rows.

Comment: Why not just check if the data is empty (`null` or `undefined`) with a simple `if statement`. And if it ends up being `true` display an empty string, eg like so `" "`. Or/ and check for those special characters and they end up being present (true), then display nothing. You could achieve that using `JS` or/ and `CSS` with `display: none` or something like `visibility: hidden;` ..etc

Comment: Issue is also observed when the filterable option is enabled for the react-table. When trying to search for some string in a column and if the respective string doesn't match any of the values in the column, special character Ã‚ is displayed in the column cell.

Comment: Please, display your [RESTful response JSON] code. I think there is where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can customize it to fit your needs. It really all depends on your API response and how it's structured, but run the code snippet and see if this is something that can be of use to you. I truly hope it does.

```js
let apiData = 'ÃdaÃtÃaÃ';

function cleanString(input) {
    var output = "";

    for (let i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
        if (input.charCodeAt(i) <= 127) {
        output += input.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return output;
}


console.log(cleanString(apiData));
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding PadRowComponent props as below, fixed the issue.

```
<ReactTable.default
              data={filteredData}
              columns={columns}             
              className="-striped -highlight"
              PadRowComponent= {<span>&nbsp;</span>}
           />
```